# SSH Keyboard Interactive access method not supported with Spring client

Tags: java, spring, session, ssh, wireshark

i am developing a Spring service that should be able to connect to a keyboard interactive ssh server, i am successfully opening a session and a channel, but using the inputStream, I receive "access method not supported". Now, this is not an exception, but perhaps a response?
It's worth to notice that when using putty i am successfully able to execute the command and get a response back.
I tried scanning the packages with Wireshark that are being sent over the network. These are the results:

Using putty to connect to the server:
58 encrypted packages (ssh)

Using spring:
28 encrypted packages (ssh)

This is my code:

```
@Component
public class UserAuthKI {

  @SneakyThrows
  public String connectAndExecuteCommand(String username, String password) {
    Session session = createSession(5, username, password);
    try {
      return createChannelExec("display-alarms", session);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return "unsuccessful connection to the ssh server";
    }
  }

  private Session createSession(int retries, String username, String password) {
    if (retries == 0) {
      throw new RuntimeException("out of tries, unable to connect to session");
    }
    try {
      String host = "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx";
      Session session = new JSch().getSession(username, host, 22);
      configureAndConnectSession(session, password);
      return session;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return createSession(retries - 1, username, password);
    }
  }

  @SneakyThrows
  private void configureAndConnectSession(Session session, String password) {
    UserInfo info = new MyUserInfo(password);
    session.setUserInfo(info);
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
  }

  @NotNull
  @SneakyThrows
  private String createChannelExec(String command, Session session) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
    channelExec.setCommand(command);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(channelExec.getInputStream());
    channelExec.connect();
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
      sb.append(sc.next());      
    }
    sc.close();
    closeSessionAndChannel(session, channelExec);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    return sb.toString();
  }

  private void closeSessionAndChannel(Session session, ChannelExec channel) {
    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
  }
```

And this is the keyboard interactive UI implementation:

```
public class MyUserInfo implements UserInfo, UIKeyboardInteractive {

  private String passwd;

  public MyUserInfo(String password) {
    this.passwd = password;
  }

  @Override
  public String getPassword() {
    return passwd;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean promptYesNo(String str) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public String getPassphrase() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean promptPassphrase(String message) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean promptPassword(String message) {
    return true;
  }
  @Override
  public void showMessage(String message) {
  }

  @Override
  public String[] promptKeyboardInteractive(String destination, String name, String instruction,String[] prompt, boolean[] echo) {
    String[] response=new String[prompt.length];
    response[0] = passwd;
    return response;
  }

}
```

Comment: If you're opening a channel, you've gotten past the authentication step. How are you actually getting this error message? What part of your code is returning it?

Comment: Also, how would you interactively run this "display-alarms" command? What happens when you run "ssh user@host display-alarms"?

Comment: The input stream is returning the response from the channel -> execChannel.getInputStream();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem, i just changed the type of the Channel,

How it was:  ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");

Fix: Channel sshChannel = session.openChannel("shell");

The problem was that the session was opening an "Exec" channel rather than a shell

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).